# How can I automate play store app creation

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

We have a template app written with `flutter` that each customer can buy a version of it and have the exact same functionality but connecting to a different database etc. Creating an app for each customer and deploying that app takes a lot of time, so we've decided to automate this process. For deploying updates of the apps, I was able to achieve that functionality very easily by integrating [`fastlane`](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/android/setup/).

The part I am stuck at is how to automate app creation with all the steps (Creating the app, filling main store listing, publishing the first version, etc.). I've searched all over the internet and not found a single solution for this. For the App store there exists the [`fastlane produce`](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/produce/) tool, but [according to the maintainers](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/discussions/16858#discussioncomment-38021) they do not plan to support an alternative for android at the moment.

As a solution I'm thinking of doing this using web scraping using tools such as `puppeteer` or `selenium`. Is there a better solution, and is doing scraping for this task a bad idea?